# Java String Split by number present in string

Tags: java, string

I have below string

String s = "I love India 1 I love India 2 I love India 3 I lo2ve India";

I want to print like below

output:

I love India

I love India

I love India

I lo2ve India

Comment: `String[] str = s.split("\\s\\d+\\s");`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `split()` on `((?<=\\d)|(^?= ))|[\\d]` like,

> String str[]= str1.split("((?<=\d)|(^?= ))|[\d]");

The below code will give you the expected output,

> ```
> static void splitString(String str1)
> {    
>     String str[]= str1.split("((?<=\\d)|(^?= )) | [\\d]");
>     for(int i=0; i<str.length; i++)
>     System.out.println(str[i]); 
>  }
> ```

Output,

> I love India
>
> I love India
>
> I love India
>
> I lo2ve India